# Tensorflow graph quantization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to quantize default SSD Mobilenet from the models repository (https://github.com/tensorflow/models).
Code for сonversion:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
  --in_graph="/home/.../mobilenet_v2.pb" \
  --out_graph="/home/.../mobilenet_v2_clean.pb" \
  --inputs=image_tensor\
  --outputs="detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections"\
  --transforms='add_default_attributes
  strip_unused_nodes
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms
  quantize_weights
  quantize_nodes
  sort_by_execution_order'
```

and then load:

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

And I get error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0d8b8f2357e8> in <module>()
      5     serialized_graph = fid.read()
      6     od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
----> 7     tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    314                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    315                 instructions)
--> 316       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    317     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
    318                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py in import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, name, op_dict, producer_op_list)
    337                 raise ValueError('Specified colocation to an op that '
    338                                  'does not exist during import: %s in %s' % (
--> 339                                      op_to_bind_to, node.name))
    340               original_op = name_to_op[op_to_bind_to]
    341               new_class_values.append(compat.as_bytes(
ValueError: Specified colocation to an op that does not exist during import: Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/strided_slice in Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/TensorArrayWrite_4/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter
```

What can be a problem? Isn't it a bug?

Comment: i am facing similar issue. Were you able to get a quantized model or atleast a model quantized just for inference part ?